# CSS select element when other element is focused

Tags: html, css, select

I have a select box and I styled it to look like an Android `Spinner`. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUsN8/1).

The problem is that I can not figure out how to make the triangle blue when the select is focused. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should use JavaScript as there are no selectors for parent's siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to travel around the DOM the wrong way. You want a nephew to affect an uncle, and you can't do that with CSS alone.

However, if you make div.triangle a sibling of select, then your CSS will work. You just need to change the positioning of the .triangle CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/6DkN6/

```
<div class="dataInputComboboxWrap">
<div class="dataInputComboboxContainer">
    <select class="dataInputCombobox"  > 
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <div class="triangle">
    </div> 
</div>
```

And to make the triangle viewable inside the Container:

```
.triangle {
    left: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can't (unless the triangle was inside the select tag, in which case you could do dataInputCombobox:focus .triange { border: 1px solid; })

You can do this with jQuery though using .addClass()